# How to Propose New April Fool's Prank

Tags: discussion, april-fools

I have an idea for an april fool's prank on SO. How would I go about pitching it to someone who could implement it?

Also, before I email them and clutter their inbox with what could possibly be an ineligible prank, what are the guidelines governing the eligibility of an April Fool's prank?

Comment: You are in the right place. Just edit your question.

Comment: You ask a question here I guess... you might be a _little_ bit early and give it all away (if anything comes of it). Maybe e-mailing would be better?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: who should I email?

Comment: You do realize April 1st is just over 8 months away?

Comment: Probably `team@stackexchange.com`.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact probably...

Comment: Yes, but the idea might be cache evicted by then. I'd rather upload it now and let the implementation procedure define its own timeline

Comment: Thanks all. I'll email team@SE and see what comes of it!

Comment: Cache evicted? What's that?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Deleted from my memory as it is not of paramount importance to what I'm doing right now (also, I'm very absent minded)

Comment: I doubt they would _delete_ it. They'd just postpone it.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: "deleted from my memory" = I'll forget

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be either the [Stack Overflow Contact page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) or emailing `team(at)stackexchange.com`. I would like to remind you though, that this is *July*, and April Fools Day is in *April*.

Comment: He's an enthusiastic... or just too emotioned to share the prank popped out his head...

Answer (score 3):

Following advice from the responses, I decided to email the StackExchange team.

The reply I received not only addressed the specific prank that I proposed but also explained the nature of pranks and thus, the guidelines that proposed pranks should be followed. Since I was unable to easily find these guidelines in the FAQ (or other similar pages), I figured it would be useful to post the guidelines here. This way, other users who would like to propose pranks can review the guidelines, thus reducing the email load on the SE team just a little.

Following are excerpts from the email I received in reply to my proposal (edited to exclude the exact nature of the prank I proposed):

> When we plan these things, we have some goals in mind:
>
> - The vast majority of folks that see the joke should realize that we can't possibly be serious
> - Ideally, the joke doesn't generate a lot of additional support overhead
> - The joke causes people to participate in various positive ways
>
> If we do pretty much anything  with reputation, we kind of miss the
>   first two points - the system is very confusing to new users as it is
>   and a joke feature such as this could end up in quite a few being even
>   more confused, or perhaps soured on the idea of participating
>   altogether. A substantial amount of traffic comes from new users
>   finding the site for the first time.

PS: I originally had this information posted under [a different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191147/190564), but merged it with this one at the suggestion of a diamond-mod.