# Several badge descriptions contain raw HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, help-center, encoding

I was reading through some badge descriptions and noticed that Synonymizer's description needs to be updated. As it stands, there is raw HTML (an `href`) in the description:

[image]

EDIT: after reading comments by @ColeJohnson, I have come to the understanding that this post comes off as whiny. I want to make it very clear that I wasn't ever trying to complain. My first reaction was to fix the perceived error myself. When I realized I was unable to do so, I figured the best course of action would be to find someone who would be able to make the necessary edits. Hence the post here.

Comment: That's a badge, not a tag.

Comment: Yes it is. PEBKAC - D'Oh!

Comment: I say we leave it like that so people will come and complain here, then we can downvote and close them as duplicates!

Comment: @ColeJohnson: and increase the load on the servers? Also, do you really want meta's image be that it doesn't care about or listen to the users of SO?

Comment: Yes. That's what meta's about. Unicorns and waffles, not complaints like this! Mwa ha ha ha ha!

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, "*this post comes off as whiny*", don't listen to him, he's high on unicorn waffles.

Comment: @OldCheckmark: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Heh, I just mean you did the right thing by reporting this on Meta.

Comment: @OldCheckmark: I think there was a PEBKAC on your end earlier. The `'t` in `don't` (and everything afterward) was cut off. Hence the confusion :). Incidentally, s/he seems to have been trolling in increasing amounts [[1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190713/190564)].

Comment: yup, looking at that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `<a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com" title="meta">2013.8.1.1299</a>` / `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="sites">2013.8.1.909</a>`

Comment: Yup looks like it's fixed, looking at &lt;a href=&quot;http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges&quot;&gt;SO's badge page&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: Still a minor issue: when viewing badge for specific user ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=1071666)) it says "Awarded 9 mins ago to" then blank space then the "for" part. Think it should be just ""Awarded 9 mins ago" and without that blank space. :)

Answer (score 5):

Inspecting the source, it seems like someone (staff) incorrectly encoded the symbols (quotes, angular brackets) as character entity references

Namely, instead of the correct HTML

```
<a href="/election">election</a>
```

Stack Overflow and co. are using this

```
&lt;a href=&quot;/election&quot;&gt;election&lt;/a&gt;
```

This happens to other badges (and individual badge pages), not just "Synonymizer".

I've seen this on SO and MSO, likely [network-wide too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191342/synonymizer-badge-description-needs-bugfix/191346#comment595149_191346).

---

### Feast your eyes on this!!!

[image]

Comment: Repro on Stack Apps, Super User, and Unix & Linux. I suspect it's network-wide.

Comment: Eyes feasted. **MAKE IT STOP**