# Migration Popup Shows Links as HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, encoding, migration

This seems to be a new bug in SO. The migration dialog is showing HTML for the links:

[image: migration-dialog]

Comment: Oh, not another HTML bug... ([the original HTML bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191342/223030))

Comment: There has been quite a number of these recently.

Comment: @likeitlikeit the root of all those bugs appears to be localization i.e. soon we'll have Stack Overflow in different languages. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy.

Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Did it really need to be reported? Couldn't it be discovered by a Dev on their own? Or do the devs not use the site...

Comment: @ColeJohnson Some bugs slip through, most don't.  Reporting a bug can only get it fixed faster, since it's another chance for a dev to notice it.  Doubt this bug would have lasted a whole day (a dev would've probably migrated something by then), but since it was reported it only lasted about 90 minutes.

Comment: the code base is updated _that_ frequently?

Comment: @ColeJohnson There were 15 deploys that touched production today (not counting Careers or the alpha Android app), with ~110 changesets total.

Comment: I never knew the sites were update _that_ much. 0_0

Comment: @Cole same snippets of code are used on many different places. Requiring a full unit test before deploying will cause great delay in all bug fixes and deployment of new features, so in my opinion it's totally fine to count on the users to find such bugs and report them.