# Why not put some fun into Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, fun

Stack Exchange is about learning. People come and ask about their problems. Others help by answering them. My Question is why Stack Exchange is not planning on adding some fun like games, quizzes and other such competition, where one can test their knowledge?

Comment: There's http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ if you want some puzzles.

Comment: I want a sausage sizzle. With fried onions. And a clown making balloon animals.

Comment: Your definition of "fun" doubtless subtly differs from mine.

Comment: If [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is not what you are looking for, then this idea sounds like a [nice proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to go for.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: Let me check code golf first. Vote down but i am still sticking there should be fun around here ;)

Comment: Maybe something like this could be suggested for [April 1st?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190713/how-to-propose-new-april-fools-prank)

Comment: @VishwasSharma I think you meant to link to the [Competitive Programming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52595/competitive-programming) proposal?

Comment: There are periodic "just for fun" competitions here on meta, for example; [Work is hard, let's color the walls](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213769/work-is-hard-lets-color-the-walls)

Comment: **Downvoting** is a real fun!

Comment: @VishwasSharma There you go

Comment: You want to spend *more* time on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @KerrekSB My point is creating signups at every point and every sub-domain is aweful, features from TopCoders like site should be implemented around and for programmers who says it will mix things up? are you that out of algos?

Comment: @pronox: Have you signed up to every SE site?! From Tex to DiY to Biblical Hermeneutics? Wow. Yeah, that would be mildly tedious to do in one sitting, though then again you get 100 rep each time you do it, so there's some kind of reward response in the brain that should make that feel fun.

Comment: @pronox If you do have a new idea of a new proposal, and you are going to put the proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), don't forget to put link here also. I'd like to check it out.

Comment: We have some [meta fun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222930/i-am-getting-an-exception-how-to-solve-it) sometimes.

Answer (score 13):

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a knowledge base, to be a one-stop site for real-life programming problems.

It is not meant to be a place to hone your skills, although being active on Stack Overflow will definitely teach you new, useful things.

If you want to exercise your actual coding skills, or even compete with others, there are plenty of other sites outside the Stack Exchange network. Like Topcoder or Project Euler.

**Edit**: As @Stijn pointed out in the comments, within the Stack Exchange network there is [CodeGolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Well Stack Overflow provides different platforms like Game Dev, Programming, Math So I guess if fun is at completely separate point one-stop approach won't be disturbed plus I didn't knew about `codegolf` but that's exactly what I was looking for.